# Is it possible to fetch the private key of an SSL certificate using java

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to fetch the private key of an SSL certificate using some SSL socket connetion.

Answer (score 1):

No. The private key remains at the owner's end. Otherwise it wouldn't be private.